# Performance testing on node.js "net"

Tags: javascript, testing, node.js, load-testing, performance-testing

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to get started with node.js "net" performance testing?

I want to see how my app will scale and want to test 10,000+ concurrent connections!

EDIT: I want to know so I can see if my Ubuntu server configs are correct, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Professional performance testing tools are agnostic to your underlying technology (node.js / .NET), and see just the output (HTTP Requests and responses), so any tools can do.

There's HP's LoadRunner and a lot of others. I have used [WebLOAD](http://www.radview.com), which is more cost effective, and a bit easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

10,000 concurrent connections.  Hmmm.   I would think that such a load would have to be tied to a user population for your app somewhere in the 500,000-2,000,000 range with a 2% to .5% level of concurrency respectively.   If this was an internal facing corporate app then your user population expectations would be somewhere in the 83,333(12%) - 125,000 (8%).    These concurrency models come from 15 years of observations in corporate and internet facing applications for levels of concurrency vs the defined user population for a given application facing model (internal corporate vs public internet).

The reason why I bring up the above is that you may be over stressing your component for its defined use and as a result you could have some engineering ghosts that you chase down to fix.  This can impact your budget and availability to hit other issues that may show up in production use.

Just food for thought,

James Pulley

Answer (score 0):

From the [video](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/05/20/video-dahl/) it seems that memory usage doesn't budge because it doesn't spawn new processes, which is precisely the reason it has picked up a huge following. That's what event driven/non blocking can do

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to know so I can see if my Ubuntu server configs are correct, etc, to see how my server will handle that.